# Jupyter: jupyter-notebook can not import module statsmodels

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed jupyter notebook in MacOS 10.9 Mavericks, using command

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

I can import some libraries like numpy, pandas and run Jupiter notebook normally, however, if I import the module statsmodels, it says No Module named "statsmodels'.

How can we run the installed library statsmodels in jupyter-notebook?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
That's because the module has been install for python2 and not for python3 that you are using as well.

Find your python3 bin related to jupyter.

```
$jupyter --paths
```

Mine was at /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/bin
run :

```
$python3 -mpip install statsmodels
```

cheers